# Kendo-ui : margin/padding within legend > item > visual

Tags: kendo-ui

I tried to apply padding or margin to have some space between legend but couldn't find any options for it. I tried like this:

```
var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.series.name, [0, 0],
                                   {fill: {color: labelColor},
                                    opacity: 0.99995,
                                    padding : 10});
```

Here is the link that I tried: http://dojo.telerik.com/UYEsiyan

Comment: Hi, I could not find any options for a vertical oriented legend. But this [forum link](https://www.telerik.com/forums/custom-visual-for-legend-in-charts---padding) has options for horizontal oriented legends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a perfect solution, but you could add an invisible rectangle to the end of the layout with the height set to the spacing you want:

```
var rectGeom = new kendo.geometry.Rect([0, 0], [50, 10]);
var rectangle = new kendo.drawing.Rect(rectGeom, {
    fill: {color: "none"},
    stroke: {color: "none"}
});         
layout.append(marker, label, space, rectangle);
layout.reflow();
```